# VBA not interpreting a string containing dual double-quote

Tags: sql, vba

I am trying to construct a string in VBA and pass it to run in SQL, and I am having this problem.

this is an example of part of the string that I want to run in SQL:

```
info_sql = "'" & info_rs!Asic & "' , '" & info_rs!Variant & "'"
```

VBA evaluates this code fine and gives me a string " 'a', 'b' "

However, the actual code I want to run is much longer, so I had to use dual double-quote in the string

```
info_sql = "'"" & info_rs!Asic & ""' , '"" & info_rs!Variant & ""' "
```

This gives me a duplicate of this string (which dual double-quote replaced with double-quote, instead of the value I want.

Does anyone know how to get around this? I tried to use CHR(34) instead of double-quote but it doesn't help.

Much thanks!

Comment: If this is constructing an SQL statement use an [ADODB.Command object with Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado) - that will take care of all of these issues and more importantly remove the current SQL Injection vulnerability you have.

Comment: can you provide us the example of complete one line string of SQL so that we can built the concatenation in vba.

Comment: ok, I think to simplify things, what I want to do is this:

I have a string variable containing "rs!Asic"  
how can I evaluate this string and output the value of Field Asic in the recordset?

Comment: Variant? can you change that name as i think it is treated as a data type

Comment: info_sql1 = Chr(34) & "'" & x & "'" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "'" & y & "'" & Chr(34)

Try this... Replace x by what you want

Comment: OUtput: " 'x' "," 'y' "

Comment: thanks, i used a slightly different method, but it works!